# Is there a way to order by value increase compared to older entries in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, sql-order-by

I want to order each ID by the percentage increase in a three day timeframe. If there is no entry three days ago, it should move up the date until today's date. In the following I have explained the layout for the database environment.

I have a table in MYSQL with the below structure (NOTE: The ID column is not unique.).

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  ID INT(3) NOT NULL,
  value INT(3) NOT NULL,
  date DATE NOT NULL
);
```

Every day there will be new values inserted for *n* number of IDs. The table will then look somewhat like this:

| ID | value | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 2020-12-08 |
| 1 | 4 | 2020-12-07 |
| 1 | 7 | 2020-12-06 |
| 1 | 5 | 2020-12-05 |
| 2 | 10 | 2020-12-08 |
| 2 | 8 | 2020-12-07 |
| 2 | 7 | 2020-12-06 |
| 3 | 10 | 2020-12-08 |
| 4 | 10 | 2020-12-08 |

For this example the SQL query should return the following order. ID 2 had the highest increase, so it is first, followed by no increase and last the decreased one.

| ID | value [current] / value [3 days ago] |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | `10 / 7 = 1.43` |
| 3 | `10 / 10 = 1` |
| 4 | `7 / 7 = 1` |
| 1 | `4 / 7 = 0.57` |

I hope my logic is sound. I have tried using the following query, however this only works if the subqueries return only one result which they should not.

```
SELECT
  (SELECT value from test GROUP BY ID ORDER BY date DESC) AS 'first',
  (SELECT value from test WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) GROUP BY ID ORDER BY date ASC) AS 'last'
```

Here is the Fiddle for the example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ded7c92/2

This is a pretty integral part of my work, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little tricky, because MySQL does not have a "first"/"last" aggregation function.  One method uses window functions:

```
select id, oldest_value, newst_value
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by date) as seqnum,
             first_value(value) over (partition by id order by date) as oldest_value,
             first_value(value) over (partition by id order by date desc) as newest_value
      from test t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
order by newest_value / oldest_value;
```

This requires MySQL 8+.  [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9335e21814b70e081e59cd47d16eec84) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Had to read up on partitions and added a WHERE clause to account for the time frame but example worked great. Thanks a lot.